# The Expendables 3 - the song when burney met ronda rousey

Tags: soundtrack

when burney met ronda rousey in the club, a song was in background.... what is the name of that track... some of the lines were like " life life this is our life " , " touch the sky "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor - Simon Curtis

great song,love it!